# What is the meaning of the code?

Tags: c++

I have read something that define a function with c define, and i can not understand the usage of [&]() -> long int.Is that assign the type of the return of function. Who can expalain it for me in detail? Thanks

```
    # define TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(expression)                 \
        [&]() -> long int                               \
        {                                               \
            long int __result;                          \   
            do  __result = (long int)(expression);      \   
            while (__result == -1L && errno == EINTR);  \
            return __result;                            \
        }()
```

Comment: That's a lambda, but it's C++, not C.

Comment: Thanks, it is realy a lambda. It seems that i shuld a systematic study of C++11

Answer (score 3):

It is a lambda expression of the form:
  **[ captures ] ( params ) -> ret { body }**

- ***[&]*** captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and current object by reference if exists
- There is no parameter
- Return type is `long int`
- ***{}*** contains definition of lambda

For details refer [cpp reference link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: And then the trailing `()` calls the lambda as soon as it's made (negating the need for a lambda in the first place?)